# No existing local cluster is suitable error using pg_dump in docker

Tags: postgresql, docker

In my docker project with postgres 9.6 I need to add support for uploading of big sql dumps.
I added pg_dump by adding in my web/Dockerfile.yml file line:

```
postgresql-client-common  \
```

as it contains pg_dump.

After building the app I enter bash and

```
# uname -a
Linux ff5146f21dbd 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux
root@ff5146f21dbd:/var/www/lprods_docker_root# pg_dump
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
root@ff5146f21dbd:/var/www/lprods_docker_root# locate -i pg_dump
```

Last command outputs nothing

```
web/Dockerfile.yml contains :
  FROM php:7.1-apache

    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    python \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    nano \
    git-core \
    curl \
    build-essential \
    openssl \
    libssl-dev \
    libgmp-dev \
    libldap2-dev \
    libpq-dev \
    netcat \
    postgresql-client-common  \
    locate \
    && git clone https://github.com/nodejs/node.git \
    && cd node \
    && git checkout v12.0.0 \
    && ./configure \
    && make \
    && make install

    RUN npm install cross-env

    RUN  docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-webp-dir=/usr/include/  --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/


    RUN  docker-php-ext-install gd pgsql pdo_pgsql zip gmp bcmath pcntl ldap sysvmsg exif \
    && a2enmod rewrite

    COPY virtualhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

and docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:

    web:
        build:
            context: ./web           # directory of web/Dockerfile.yml
            dockerfile: Dockerfile.yml

        environment:
            - APACHE_RUN_USER=#1000
            # - APACHE_RUN_USER=www-data

        container_name: lprods_web

        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        ports:
            - "8086:80"
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}



    db:
        image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
        container_name: lprods_db
        ports:
            - '5433:5432'
        restart: always
        environment: 
            POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: '1'
            POSTGRES_DB: 'wprods'
        volumes:
            - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/


    phppgadmin:
        image: dockage/phppgadmin:latest
        environment:
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_HOST=db
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_PORT=5432
            - PHP_PG_ADMIN_SERVER_DEFAULT_DB=postgres
        container_name: lprods_phppgadmin

        restart: always
        ports:
            - "8087:80"
            - "443:443"
        links:
            - db


    composer:
        image: composer:1.6
        container_name: lprods_composer
        volumes:
            - ${APP_PATH_HOST}:${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        working_dir: ${APP_PTH_CONTAINER}
        command: composer install  --ignore-platform-reqs
```

Why error and how to fix it?

**MODIFIED :**

I have

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

But checking version I got error :

```
# /usr/bin/pg_dump -v
Warning: No existing local cluster is suitable as a default target. Please see man pg_wrapper(1) how to specify one.
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

The same error I got when running psql command(actually I need it):

```
 /usr/bin/psql  -h localhost  -d wprods -U  postgres  -W -f "/var/www/lprods_docker_root/wprods_2017_10_23.sql" 
Error: You must install at least one postgresql-client-<version> package
```

What is wrong with my configuration ?

**MODIFIED 2:**

In my docker-compose.yml I have :

```
db:
    image: postgres:9.6.10-alpine
    ...
    volumes:
        - ./init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

Is it?

command :

```
locate -i postgresql.conf
```

outputs nothing

```
find /usr -name "postgresql.conf"
```

Also outputs nothing.

Also I have :

```
# ps -ef | grep postgres
root        28    21  0 08:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep postgres
```

What did I miss ?

Comment: does `apt list --installed` show `postgresql-client-common`?  And what does `find /usr -name "pg_dump"` reveal?

Comment: Yes, it found : find /usr -name "pg_dump"
/usr/bin/pg_dump

Comment: Odd, then what is `echo $PATH`?  If `locate` can't find `pg_dump`, then I suspect your `$PATH` is messed up

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED

Comment: I hope i'm reading it right--did you ever `initdb`?  Do you have a `postgresql.conf` lying around somewhere, and is postgres even running (i.e., `ps -ef | grep postgres`)?

Comment: Please, look at MODIFIED 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`postgresql-client-common`](https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/18.04/ubuntu-main-amd64/postgresql-client-common_190_all.deb.html) is a Ubuntu-specific package of scripts that allows users to work with multiple versions of Postgres (or multiple database clusters).  It provies several scripts and symlinks that essentially override the functions of "real" postgres utilities (like `pg_dump`):

```
root@foo:/usr/bin# ls -al | grep pg_dump
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        37 Feb  8  2018 pg_dump -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        37 Feb  8  2018 pg_dumpall -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

You may need to also install `postgresql-client-10` to make `pg_dump` work.

Note also that you have only installed the client tools.  If you need to get a fully-functional PostgreSQL database up and running, I believe you will also need to install the `postgresql-10` package